# NFS mount point as a disk device linux

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, disk

1. A remote NAS server provides an NFS share (/myShare) to a linux client machine
2. From the linux client , I mounted the NFS share ( Eg./mnt/myShare )

My question is , Is it possible to convert this /mnt/myShare as a disk device (eg./dev/mydevice)

I would like to use this disk   as a physical disk itself to a container to store its data.

Can device mapper be of help here.. Any leads would be of help here

--kk

Comment: A file is basically an abstraction of a block device. Qemu uses qcow files, for example. So its possible.

Comment: Thanks @stark.  Does this means we create qemu files on to the mount point and point  it to the guest as a virtio block type of device ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to convert this /mnt/myShare as a disk device (eg./dev/mydevice)

The answer is yes and no. Yes, because you can mount everything anywhere, i.e. you can:

```
mount -t nfs nas:/myShare /dev/mydevice
```

(provided that the directory `/dev/mydevice` exists).

NO, because a disk is a file under /dev, which basically exposes a set of sectors (or clusters) - other OS components use that to present a file system, which then is mounted somewhere else.

You, instead, have *already* a file which represents a file system. You can mount that file system wherever you want. 99% of your OS, and your programs, will not care  about.

But your share is **not** a disk, because it is something (a directory part of a file system) exported by another machine. And this difference cannot be circumvented. I think you can live with this without problems but, if your question is literally correct, then no: an exported share is not a disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the raw hard drive, then you don't need a filesystem. Perhaps your NAS server can be configured to export its storage as an [iSCSI target](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI).

NFS itself doesn't implement storage as block device.

**But** what you can do is the following:

1. Mount `/myShare` onto `/mnt/myShare`.
2. Create a file the size of all of `myShare`. For example, if `myShare` is 3TB in size, do `truncate -s 3T /mnt/myShare/loop.img`. (at this point, if you wanted a filesystem, you could have done `mkfs -t ext4 /mnt/myShare/loop.img`).
3. Set up the file as a loop device: `sudo losetup /dev/loop7 /mnt/myShare/loop.img`
4. You now have a 3TB block device on `/dev/loop7`, which you can see in the output of `grep loop7 /proc/partitions`.